# Cambiar el color de fondo de un Gtk::Button con Ruby

Tags: ruby, interfaz-gráfica, gtk

Estoy haciendo una pequeña aplicación GUI usando Ruby y la biblioteca Gtk3, pero quiero cambiar el color de fondo de un Button, pero no he obtenido resultados positivos, aqui mi ultimo intento hasta el momento, si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradecería bastante

```
 suma = Gtk::Button.new(:label => " ➕ ")                     │
 suma.set_background_color(:color => "red")
```